# Stratified sampling in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data set which contains user and purchase data. Here is an example, where first element is userId, second is productId, and third indicate boolean.

```
(2147481832,23355149,1)
(2147481832,973010692,1)
(2147481832,2134870842,1)
(2147481832,541023347,1)
(2147481832,1682206630,1)
(2147481832,1138211459,1)
(2147481832,852202566,1)
(2147481832,201375938,1)
(2147481832,486538879,1)
(2147481832,919187908,1)
...
```

I want to make sure I only take 80% of each users data and build an RDD while take the rest of the 20% and build a another RDD. Lets call train and test. I would like to stay away from using groupBy to start with since it can create memory problem since data set is large. Whats the best way to do this?

I could do following but this will not give 80% of each user.

```
val percentData = data.map(x => ((math.random * 100).toInt, x._1. x._2, x._3)
val train = percentData.filter(x => x._1 < 80).values.repartition(10).cache()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One possible solution is in Holden's answer, and here is some other solutions :

**Using RDDs :**

You can use the sampleByKeyExact transformation, from the [PairRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) class.

> **sampleByKeyExact**(boolean withReplacement, scala.collection.Map fractions, long seed) 
>   Return a subset of this RDD sampled by key (via stratified sampling) containing exactly math.ceil(numItems * samplingRate) for each stratum (group of pairs with the same key).

And this is how I would do :

Considering the following list :

```
val seq = Seq(
                (2147481832,23355149,1),(2147481832,973010692,1),(2147481832,2134870842,1),(2147481832,541023347,1),
                (2147481832,1682206630,1),(2147481832,1138211459,1),(2147481832,852202566,1),(2147481832,201375938,1),
                (2147481832,486538879,1),(2147481832,919187908,1),(214748183,919187908,1),(214748183,91187908,1)
           )
```

I would create an `RDD` Pair, mapping all the users as keys :

```
val data = sc.parallelize(seq).map(x => (x._1,(x._2,x._3)))
```

Then I'll set up `fractions` for each key as following, since  **`sampleByKeyExact`** takes a Map of fraction for each key :

```
val fractions = data.map(_._1).distinct.map(x => (x,0.8)).collectAsMap
```

What I have done here is mapping on the keys to find distinct keys and then associate each to a fraction equals to `0.8`. I collect the whole as a Map.

To sample now :

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
val sampleData = data.sampleByKeyExact(false, fractions, 2L)
```

or

```
val sampleData = data.sampleByKeyExact(withReplacement = false, fractions = fractions,seed = 2L)
```

You can check the count on your keys or data or data sample :

```
scala > data.count
// [...]
// res10: Long = 12

scala > sampleData.count
// [...]
// res11: Long = 10
```

**Using DataFrames :**

Let's consider the same data (`seq`) from the previous section.

```
val df = seq.toDF("keyColumn","value1","value2")
df.show
// +----------+----------+------+
// | keyColumn|    value1|value2|
// +----------+----------+------+
// |2147481832|  23355149|     1|
// |2147481832| 973010692|     1|
// |2147481832|2134870842|     1|
// |2147481832| 541023347|     1|
// |2147481832|1682206630|     1|
// |2147481832|1138211459|     1|
// |2147481832| 852202566|     1|
// |2147481832| 201375938|     1|
// |2147481832| 486538879|     1|
// |2147481832| 919187908|     1|
// | 214748183| 919187908|     1|
// | 214748183|  91187908|     1|
// +----------+----------+------+
```

We will need the underlying `RDD` to do that on which we creates tuples of the elements in this `RDD` by defining our key to be the first column :

```
val data: RDD[(Int, Row)] = df.rdd.keyBy(_.getInt(0))
val fractions: Map[Int, Double] = data.map(_._1)
                                      .distinct
                                      .map(x => (x, 0.8))
                                      .collectAsMap

val sampleData: RDD[Row] = data.sampleByKeyExact(withReplacement = false, fractions, 2L)
                               .values

val sampleDataDF: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(sampleData, df.schema) // you can use sqlContext.createDataFrame(...) instead for spark 1.6)
```

You can now check the count on your keys or `df` or data sample :

```
scala > df.count
// [...]
// res9: Long = 12

scala > sampleDataDF.count
// [...]
// res10: Long = 10
```

Since **Spark 1.5.0** you can use `DataFrameStatFunctions.sampleBy` method:

```
df.stat.sampleBy("keyColumn", fractions, seed)
```

Comment: This is great, can I do the subtract to get the 20%? or do you recommend a better solution?

Comment: well once you have the new rdd, you can do anything with it.

Comment: I see the sample method available on the rdd but not the sampleByKeyExact

Comment: what version of spark are you using? it's actually a [PairRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions)

Comment: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1"`,`"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.4.1"`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is may be well suited to something like "Blink DB", but lets look at the question. There are two ways to interpret what you've asked one is:

1) You want 80% of your users, and you want all of the data for them.
2) You want 80% of each users data

For #1 you could do a map to get the user ids, call distinct, and then sample 80% of them (you may want to look at `kFold` in `MLUtils` or `BernoulliCellSampler`). You can then filter your input data to just the set of IDs you want.

For #2 you could look at `BernoulliCellSampler` and simply apply it directly.