# Partitioning a dataframe in order to have a minimum amount of data for each class label (stratified partitioning)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to partitioning a dataframe in a stratified way. That is, the dataframe has a column with a lots of zeros and just a few ones values. And I would like to partition it keeping the ratio between zeros and ones using a Custom Partitioner, but I don't know how can I do it.

Here [Stratified sampling with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637760/stratified-sampling-with-pyspark) and here [Stratified sampling in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238727/stratified-sampling-in-spark/32241887#32241887) I have found similar situations but using sampling instead partitioning. Any idea? This is the first time I'm trying to partitionate the data in a custom way. I'm using Spark + Scala + Dataframes

Comment: check this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476540/4758823

Comment: This answer is similar what I want, but split data into two dataframe. In my case, I want to partitioning data, so each worker/node recieves data with similar proportion between class labels.