# sampleBy returns very skewed results

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark (1.5.2) DataFrames and trying to get a Stratified dataset. My data has been prepped for binary classification and there are only the two values for `class`, 1 and 0.

```
val Array(trainingData, testData) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val fractions: Map[Int, Double] = Map(1 -> 0.5, 0 -> 0.5)

val trainingData3 = trainingData.stat.sampleBy("class", fractions, new Random().nextLong)

println("Training True Class = " + trainingData3.where("class=1").count())
println("Training False Class = " + trainingData3.where("class=0").count())
```

On the console I get an output showing a vastly incorrect ratio of class 1 to 0:

```
Training True Class = 799845
Training False Class = 32797260
```

Answer (score 5):

The fraction provided to `sampleBy` for DataFrames, as with 'sampleByKeyExact' and `sampleByKey` for RDD's, is not the percentage you want in the end result set. Rather it's the percentage you wish to keep from the original dataset.

To get a 50/50 split you need to compare counts of class 1 and class 0 in the full dataset, get the ratio, and then use those to help select your fractions.

So for example if 98% of records are class 0 and 2% are class 1 and you want a 50/50 split then you might use a fraction of class 1=100% and class 0=2%.

```
val fractions: Map[Int, Double] = Map(1 -> 1.0, 0 -> 0.02)
```

Comment: You might be looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32241887/3415409