# PySpark sampleBy different fraction per column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` that contains a column `"freq"` that for each row represents the probability that the row is selected for output. I am currently sampling using sampleBy:

```
frac = dict(
    (e.freq, e.freq)
    for e
    in df.select("freq").distinct().collect()
)
result = df.sampleBy("freq", fractions = frac)
```

This is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516805/how-to-select-a-same-size-stratified-sample-from-a-dataframe-in-apache-spark), but it does not seem too clean. Is there a way to do the same thing that avoids creating a dummy dictionary that acts like `lambda x: x`

Edit:

Say the dataset is

```
+-----+----+---- 
| Name|freq| other columns
|Alice| 0.3|
|  Bob| 0.2|
|  Joe| 0.3|
...
```

I want the final dataframe to contain Alice and Joe's rows each with probability 0.3, Bob's row with probability 0.2 and so on.